# How to create an array of objects with different indicies in the React state

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state

I am trying to create an array (`todos`) with the same objects in the state of my React Component. The object is supposed to consist of an `active:false,` value and its index.

I tried this:

```
this.state = {
      todos:Array(15).fill({active:false},{idx:???})
}
```

What do I write as the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip `.fill` by spreading `Array(15)` into an array and then you can just `.map`. But why are you making an empty array first if you already have values that you want to populate?

```
[...Array(15)].map((_, idx) => {
  return {active: false, idx}
})
```

Comment: oh, i have exactly 15 todos and only need to update their status. So I thought I'm creating them in the constructor and then just update their status based on their index. Is that correct ?

Comment: Made a syntax mistake. Above works. As long as your implementation works, then by all means use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can write an index in array as `idx` to the object:

```
Array(15).fill({ active: false }).map((i, k) => ({ ...i, ...{ idx: k }}));
```

But you need to use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate throw array one more time and create a new array with indexes.